# Drop table which is currently in use [sybase]

Tags: database, datatable, sybase

Is there any way to force drop a table in sybase which is currently in use ?
Or any way to get rid of the lock.

Force drop will be a better option. But does a force drop exist ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No you can't because if it does, Sybase would break the integrity of the database.
Imagine : an user is reading datas from a table and at the same time another is destroying this same table !!

If you want to force it, you have to turn on the database into "single-user" and after that no one -but you- will can connect to the database and do what you want...

try http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=220392&page=49
for switching to single user.

Answer (score 2):

Sybase is totally online, and multi-user, no need for single user mode.

If you have enough privilege you can perform various actions.  None of these actions "break data or database or referential integrity" that id already defined in DDL:

- if the problem is that the table (not pages) is locked, and you want you eliminate the table lock, which is preventing other users accessing the table, `kill` the `spid`.  `sp_lock` will identify the `server process id`.
- if you actually want to drop the table, but it is locked, first `kill` the `spid`; then drop the table.

(There is a "force drop" command, but that is undocumented and unsupported; more important it is for special cases, not necesary for your case.)

Comment: Ok, but in production if the table is often locked, good luck ! and please the undocumented mode :(

Comment: @Stef. Er, what is the problem in killing a spid that has locks held, in production ?  I do it all the time, no luck involved. Do you have any Sybase experience ?

Comment: @Stef. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), the **Be Honest** section. We are encouraged to correct incorrect info. 1) you have posted complete misinformation, and I have pointed that out so you can correct it. 2) you have votes my answer down, in retaliation, with no basis, you cannot identify anything that is incorrect. When I question you about technical specifics, you change the subject. SO is not a blog site, it is for questions and **accurate** answers. **Be Honest**.  Now, have you ever administered Sybase ? In production ?